# payment date if subscription payment fails and then succeeds

Tags: paypal

I am setting up a 1 month Standard Paypal subscription with IPN. I haven't found any documentation that explains when a payment is made next month, if the payment first failed, but was than successful. This is all very confusing so let's take an example:

A payment is **completed** on **10.1.2018**. **Next** month on **10.2.2018**, payment fails. Paypal **reattempts** payment after 5 days, thats on **15.2.2018**. That payment is successful.

Next month, another payment will take place, but I am not sure when. Will the next payment be made on 15.3.2018 (1 month after the last successful payment) or 10.3.2018 (1 month after the initial failed payment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Next month, another payment will take place, but I am not sure when.
>   Will the next payment be made on 15.3.2018 (1 month after the last
>   successful payment) or 10.3.2018 (1 month after the initial failed
>   payment)?

Payment will take place at **10.03.2018**

**Reattempt example** from [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/reattempt_failed_payment/)

Subscription terms:

```
A regular subscription for $20.00 USD a month, for one year
```

Bob signs up for the subscription on Feb. 12.

```
On Mar. 12, PayPal attempts to collect Bob's recurring $20.00 payment for March, and the payment succeeds.
On Apr. 12, PayPal attempts to collect Bob's recurring $20.00 payment, but the payment fails because of a temporary limit placed on Bob's PayPal account.
On Apr. 15, PayPal reattempts to collect Bob's recurring $20.00 payment for April, but the payment fails again because the temporary limit remains on Bob's PayPal account.
On Apr. 18, Bob takes action on his PayPal account, and PayPal lifts the temporary limit.
On Apr. 20, PayPal reattempts to collect Bob's recurring $20.00 payment for April, and the payment succeeds.
On May 12, PayPal attempts to collect Bob's recurring $20.00 payment for May, and the payment succeeds.
```